# Why does AWS Lambda function trigger multiple ECS Fargate containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

**AWS Lambda function firing multiple times and starting multiple ECS Fargate containers**

I have a long-running process that I have defined as an AWS Fargate containerized task. This task is triggered using ecs.runTask(taskParams, callback) api call from an AWS Lambda function. The Lambda function is triggered by a notification of a file uploaded into an S3 bucket.

This executes the function multiple times, we wrote idempotent code, by using the filename of the file that was uploaded, as well as some unique service id, for this particular service we are trying to create - then writing this to a DB, when the second or other lambda functions execute, it should not be able to insert the same record, as this is unique.

So my issue is this, the function does the insert and I can see through CloudWatch that the other instances, return a value stating that the DB insert could not be done, as there is already an entry like this...and then exits.

Based on the response, if success we have an ECS task that fires to start a AWS Fargate container... part of our function looks like this

```
console.log("Loading function");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const { stat } = require("fs");
const ecs = new aws.ECS();
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const https = require("https");


exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log("Received event:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  console.log("EventId:", context.awsRequestId);

  // Get the object from the event
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const fileName = decodeURIComponent(
    event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " ")
  );

  try {
    let configData = await readConfigDataFromS3(bucket, fileName);
    console.log("EndPoint:", configData.Api.EndPoint);
    console.log("ServiceId:", configData.CustomService.ServiceId);

    //init request data to post to custom service
    let customServiceRequestData = {
      ServiceId: configData.CustomService.ServiceId,
      Status: 0,
      FileName: fileName,
    };

    console.log(
      "Posting data:",
      JSON.stringify(customServiceRequestData, null, 2)
    );

    
    let statusId = "";
    //make http post request to custom service
    await makeHttpPostRequest(
      configData.Api.EndPoint,
      "path here",
      customServiceRequestData
    )
      .then((response) => {
        // Handle the response here
        console.log("Response:", response);

        if (response.indexOf("}") > -1)
        {
          console.log("Response is JSON");
          var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
          statusId = responseObj.Id;
        } else {
          console.log("Response is not JSON");
          statusId = "";
        }
        
        // this will be the status id returned from the custom service 
        console.log("Response StatusId: [", statusId,"]");

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        // Handle the error here
      });

    console.log("After Post Request ServiceStatusId:", statusId);


    //run task in ECS on success
    if (statusId != "" && statusId != null && statusId != undefined) {

      //run task in ECS
      console.log("Before ECS Task", statusId);
      await runTask(bucket, fileName, statusId, context);
      console.log("After ECS Task");
    } else {
      console.log("Not running ECS Task");
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};


//read config data from s3
async function readConfigDataFromS3(bucket, filename) {
 ...
}
//run task in ECS
async function runTask(bucket, filenamekey, statusid, context) {
 ...
}
//make http post request
async function makeHttpPostRequest(url, path, input) {
  ...
}
```

I can see that the other instances return "Not running ECS Task" - but what bothers me, is that when I check on ECS - there are also multiple containers starting up why would this happen, as I never execute ecs.runTask for the others?

Here is the logs for the first lamda function:
[Lambda Function Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukgof.png)

And this is what the others would typically look like:
[Other Lambda Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJSXA.png)

I can see on the firt log - that it is entering the call twice why would this be:
[First Lambda - entering this twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsQAX.png)

Here is the code for the function runTask:

```
//run task in ECS
async function runTask(bucket, filenamekey, statusid, context) {
  console.log("starting the container processing service: " + statusid);

  var params = {
    taskDefinition: "TASK DEF HERE",
    cluster: "CLUSTER HERE",
    launchType: "FARGATE",
    platformVersion: "LATEST",
    count: 1,
    networkConfiguration: {
      awsvpcConfiguration: {
        subnets: [
          /* required */
          "subnet-1272d959",
          /* more items */
        ],
        assignPublicIp: "ENABLED",
        securityGroups: [
          "sg-0f095dfe517ee22ae",
          /* more items */
        ],
      },
    },
    tags: [
      {
        key: "bucket",
        value: bucket,
      },
      {
        key: "filenamekey",
        value: filenamekey,
      },
      {
        key: "statusid",
        value: statusid,
      }
    ],
    overrides: {
      containerOverrides: [
        {
          command: [bucket, filenamekey, statusid],
          name: "---NAME---",
          cpu: 512,
          memory: 4096,
          memoryReservation: 4096,
          environment: [
            {
              name: "--NAME---",
              value: "dev",
            },
            {
              name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
              value: "FargateTask",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      cpu: "512",
      memory: "4096",
    },
  };

  console.log("Before ECS runTask");
  await ecs
    .runTask(params, function (err, data) {
      console.log(`IN TASK - ${params.overrides.containerOverrides[0].command[0]}`);

      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        console.log("ERROR");
      } else {
        console.log(data); // successful response
        console.log("SUCCESS");
      }
      context.done(err, data);
    })
    .promise();

  console.log("After ECS runTask");
}
```

Any suggestions on not getting to the point where we have multiple Fargate containers running?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full Lambda function code. It would also be helpful to see the logged `event` object that gets passed into each Lambda invocation. There may be a clue in the events as to why it is running multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It seem the following code in my lambda function is executing the ecs.runtask multiple times:

```
    await ecs
        .runTask(params, function (err, data) {
          console.log(`IN TASK - ${params.overrides.containerOverrides[0].command[0]}`);
    
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            console.log("ERROR");
          } else {
            console.log(data); // successful response
            console.log("SUCCESS");
          }
          context.done(err, data);
        })
        .promise();
```

I have updated this to only do:

```
await ecs.runTask(params).promise();
```

And this fixed the issue, although I would still like to know why?